# How do I render to the browser a PDF using PDFKit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I have the following link_to path:

http://localhost:3000/letters/showpdf/3

I have the following custom action in my letters controller:

```
 def showpdf

 @letter = Letter.find(params[:id])
 @redcloth_letter = " <style type='text/css'>  </style>"

 @redcloth_letter = @redcloth_letter << RedCloth.new(@letter.body).to_html

 pdf = PDFKit.new(@redcloth_letter)
 pdf.stylesheets << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets/compiled/pdf.css"

 send_data(pdf.to_pdf, :filename => "pdf.pdf")

 end
```

I currently get nothing returning to the browser.

*EDIT:  This is what I see in the ruby logs:*

```
Processing LettersController#showpdf (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-18 15:10:31) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"showpdf", "id"=>"3", "controller"=>"letters"}
  Letter Load (1.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "letters" WHERE ("letters"."id" = 3) 
Sending data pdf.pdf
Completed in 1917ms (View: 6, DB: 2) | 200 OK [http://localhost/letters/showpdf/3]
```

Comment: do you have Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf in your environment.rb ? i wrote the same code you did and everything works fine. also what do you mean by getting nothing returning to the browser? does an empty pdf pop-up? or nothing like so?

Comment: @andrew thank you for response to my question.  Um, I used to have a Mime type but removed it.  I get zero response, and no pop up.  I will add the Mime type line and see...

Comment: @andrew I added the Mime type to environment.rb and nothing pops-up.  My expected behavior is to have a pop-up that displays the pdf.  Am I using send_data right?  Note that .pdf is NOT in the URL...it should still work as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use in my controller with PDFkit.

```
send_data @pdf, :filename => "whatever.pdf",
                :type => "application/pdf",
                :disposition  => "inline" # either "inline" or "attachment"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Inline worked for me. Attachment tried to download the file.

Comment: thank you! didn't know about `send_data` until I found this